# How to Open and Cancel EditItemTemplate in clientside

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

How to Open and cancel list view row in edit mode through javascript ?
I use sever method to open the row , but i have to bind list view again every time.

i want to find the equivalent javascript method to these lines :

```
ListFamilyRelation.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;//EDIT

ListFamilyRelation.EditIndex = -1;//CANCEL
```

---

**Server Method :**

```
protected void ListFamilyRelation_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
            {
                ListFamilyRelation.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
                FamilyRelationRepository familyrepationRepo = new FamilyRelationRepository();

                List<FAMILYRELATION> familyrelationList = familyrepationRepo.All.ToList();
                ListFamilyRelation.DataSource = familyrelationList;
                ListFamilyRelation.DataBind();
            }
```

---

**My Templates :**

```
          <ItemTemplate>

                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 code">
                            <%#:Item.RELATION_CODE%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 name">
                            <%#:Item.RELATION_NAME%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">

                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit"  CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-md white_cr"  >Edit</asp:LinkButton>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </ItemTemplate>



            <AlternatingItemTemplate>

                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 code">
                            <%#:Item.RELATION_CODE%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 name">
                            <%#:Item.RELATION_NAME%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-md white_cr"  >Edit</asp:LinkButton>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </AlternatingItemTemplate>

            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 code">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 name">

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </InsertItemTemplate>

            <EditItemTemplate>
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 code">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUpCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RELATION_CODE") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 name">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUpRelation" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RELATION_NAME") %>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update1</asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </EditItemTemplate>
```

---

Comment: did you tried this(http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-asp-net-listview-control-using-jquery-ajax-and-web-services)

Comment: @ManishGoswami : it's  a popup not inline